# how to call Partialview inside another view in asp.net mvc

Tags: ajax, redirect, asp.net-mvc-5, rendering, partial-views

If i click Execute button i m redirecting my action to viewpage(GetSection), in this page the partialview(CoverPage) should render automaticly without any event, all it has navbar and CoverPage is also part of navbar, all navbar values are coming from database, i tried "@Html.RenderPartial("CoverPage")" syntax, but it doesn't work for me,and here is my View page

```
<table style="width:auto">
    @foreach (Test_Section p in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div id="ajaxnav" class="navbar-left">
                    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                        <li class="navigationLink">
                   @Ajax.ActionLink(p.SectionName, p.Title, new { id = p.StdSectionId },
                   new AjaxOptions
                   {
                       UpdateTargetId = "getHtml",
                       InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                       HttpMethod = "GET"
                   }, new { style = "color:black" , @class = "navigationLink" })


                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>

    }
    <div id="getHtml" class="divhtml"></div>
</table>
```

and the controller is

```
public ActionResult GetSections()
        {
            Test_Section[] section = context.Test_Section.ToArray();
            return PartialView(section);
        }
```

so please help me.

Comment: Where are you calling the partial view ? Did you try `@Html.Partial("CoverPage")`

Comment: In ajax .actionlink im pulling all partialviews links from database(navbar). and there along with i want to display any 1 partialviews

Comment: You said you want to load partial view without any event.But now you are saying you want it with ajax action link. Can you update your question with clear information ?

Comment: i have GetSection action, here i am pulling all Partial Views links from DB using Ajax, and here i want to 1st partial views without any click event on retrived link from DB

Answer (score 1):

From your comments, it looks like you want to load the response of the click event of the first link on the page load.

You can trigger the link click on the document ready event with jquery `trigger` method.

```
$(function () {

    if ($("a.navigationLink").length) {
       $("a.navigationLink").eq(0).trigger( "click" );
    }

});
```

Comment: how to select or apply CSS for 1st link of the navbar

Comment: `$("a.navigationLink").eq(0)` is the first link (wrapped jquery object). You can apply css class to that like ` `$("a.navigationLink").eq(0).addClass("yourCssClassName")` or use the jquery `css` method